# Why is `$str1 =~ "foo"` recognized as `$str1 =~ m/foo/` (and not a syntax error)?

Tags: regex, perl

I recently saw code from someone who's not familiar with Perl.
He wanted to compare two strings for equality but didn't know about
the `eq` operator, so he used `=~` like this:

```
my $str1 = 'foobar';
my $str2 = 'bar';
if ( $str1 =~ $str2 ) {
    print "strings are equal\n";
}
```

Another snippet was

```
if ( $str1 =~ "foo" ) {
    print "string equals 'foo'\n";
}
```

Of course it should simply read `$str1 eq $str2` and `$str1 eq "foo"` to avoid false-positives.

I run the code through `Deparse` and it said everything is ok:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'use strict; 
                       use warnings; 
                       my $str1="foobar"; 
                       my $str2="bar"; 
                       $str1 =~ $str2; 
                       $str1 =~ "bar";'
use warnings;
use strict;
my $str1 = 'foobar';
my $str2 = 'bar';
$str1 =~ /$str2/;
$str1 =~ /bar/;
-e syntax OK
```

I looked through the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators), but from my understanding
the situation is as follows:

- The general syntax is `m/pattern/`.
- **Either** use `m` and a delimiter of your choice instead of `/` (but be aware that `'` and `?` have special meaning)
- **Or** leave off the `m` but then the delimiter *must* be `/`.

But apparently Perl understands `$str1 =~ "foo"` as `$str1 =~ m/foo/` although no `m` is present. Why is that? I'd expected that to be a syntax error.

Comment: You're looking in the wrong section of the docs: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Ah, thank you for that link. Indeed this was the information I was looking for. There should be some link from "my" section to "your" section, though.

Comment: I think there are few places where the docs mention examples as **/regex/**, but it works as well with just **"regex"**. For instance, split works like that.

Comment: @blackpen Good point, but the docs for `split` clearly mention that. The docs for `m//` don't.

Comment: @PerlDog, what I was pointing out is that split works even when you give the pattern in double quotes (even though the docs explicitely mention double slashes).

Comment: @blackpen Ok. I thought split accepts quotes only for a single space, like `" "` and then does its special handling (because `/ /` and `" "` are not the same for `split`).

Comment: @PerlDog The issue is that it's the **user** of the string that decides whether it will convert a string to a regular expression. So you need to look in the documentation of the user. So it's mentioned in the `split` documentation and the `=~` documentation.

Comment: BTW, `$str =~ "foo"` is not the same as `$str eq "foo"`. Since the regexp isn't anchored, it will match a string that has `foo` anywhere in it, e.g. `"This has foo in it"`.

Comment: Yes, @Barmar, that was the issue. The programmer's _intention_ was `eq` but he (wrongly) used `=~` instead. I spotted that in a codereview and wondered why it works at all.

Comment: @PerlDog It would work if he used `=~ '^foo$'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *I'd expected that to be a syntax error.*

Quoting the documentation for `=~` in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html),

> If the right argument is an expression rather than a search pattern, substitution, or transliteration, it is interpreted as a search pattern at run time.

---

> *But apparently Perl understands `$str1 =~ "foo"` as `$str1 =~ m/foo/` although no `m` is present. Why is that?*

Why not? I can't think of a reason not to have `=~` imply a match operator if there's no match, substitution or transliteration operator on its RHS. I'd use

```
$s =~ /foo/
```

over

```
$s =~ "foo"
```

but I have used

```
$s =~ $re
```

Especially when the value of `$re` is a pattern compiled by `qr//`.

Comment: I totally agree. I usually use `/foo/` or `$s =~ $re` (given `$re = qr/…/`) but was wondering why `$s =~ "foo"` works because I couldn't find the docs for that.

Comment: Obviously, because it was programmed that to do that.  /// Actually, it is documented "If the right argument is an expression rather than a search pattern, substitution, or transliteration, it is interpreted as a search pattern at run time."

Comment: I was looking in the wrong section of the docs. I read about [`m//` and Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) but should have read about [`=~`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators). The latter clears things up. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The `=~` operator expects a scalar expression no the left and a pattern match on the right.  From [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators):

> Binary "=~" binds a scalar expression to a pattern match. Certain operations search or modify the string $_ by default. This operator makes that kind of operation work on some other string. The right argument is a search pattern, substitution, or transliteration. The left argument is what is supposed to be searched, substituted, or transliterated instead of the default $_ .
>   ...
>   If the right argument is an expression rather than a search pattern, substitution, or transliteration, it is interpreted **as a search pattern at run time.**

The actual interpretation of the right hand side can be... tricky.  The details can be found in the Perl Documentation's ["Gory Details of Parsing Quoted Constructs"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Gory-details-of-parsing-quoted-constructs), the summary of which is:

> When presented with something that might have several different interpretations, Perl uses the **DWIM** (that's "Do What I Mean") principle to pick the most probable interpretation. This strategy is so successful that Perl programmers often do not suspect the ambivalence of what they write. But from time to time, Perl's notions differ substantially from what the author honestly meant.
>   ...
>   The most important Perl parsing rule is the first one discussed below: when processing a quoted construct, Perl first finds the end of that construct, then interprets its contents. If you understand this rule, you may skip the rest of this section on the first reading. The other rules are likely to contradict the user's expectations much less frequently than this first one.

Comment: Nothing tricky about it. As I mentioned down below, If the RHS isn't an explicit match, substitution or transliteration operator, it's an implicit match operator.

Comment: Re "*When presented with something that might have several different interpretations*", That's not the case here. There's no grammatical ambiguity. There is only one possible interpretation. This paragraph isn't relevant to the question at hand.

Comment: Re "*The most important Perl parsing rule is the first one discussed below*", I think you misunderstood what this paragraph means because it  has no relevance to the question at hand. It explains, among other things, why `"foo $foo{"bar"} bar"` is a syntax error.