# Matching a string which contain "\" character

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to match a string that contains a `\` character but it does not work as expected.

For example:

```
if ("\\" =~ "\\") {
    print "true\n";
}
```

In this case it work and prints `true` as expected.

However in case I put more characters before and after the `\` character, the condition becomes false and it does not print anything on the standard output

```
if ("DATA\\DATA" =~ "DATA\\DATA") {
    print "true\n";
}
```

Although the `if` condition is still true if I put characters on 1 side of the `\` character (`DATA\\` or `\\DATA`).

Answer (score 7):

When I try your first code, I actually get this error:

```
Trailing \ in regex m/\/ at foo.pl line 1.
```

That's a hint as to what the problem is.

The `=~` operator can take several forms. Usually it's `$str =~ tr/.../.../` for a transliteration, `$str =~ s/.../.../` for a regex search/replace, or `$str =~ m/.../` for a plain regex match.

Your code uses none of these. Instead it uses the general `$str =~ EXPR` form, which evaluates EXPR as a string, then interprets the contents of that string as a regex (and performs a normal match as with `m//`).

In your case (code 1), the resulting string consists of a single backslash: `\`. This is not a valid regex because in a regex, a backslash must be followed by something. That's why the above error occurs.

In your other example (code 2), the resulting string is `DATA\DATA`. When interpreted as a regex, this matches `DATA`, followed by a non-digit character (that's what `\D` means in a regex), followed by `ATA`.

To fix this, you can either double all your backslashes (`"DATA\\\\DATA"` - string processing turns this into `DATA\\DATA`, which is the regex for matching the literal string `DATA\DATA`), or simply not use strings in the first place:

```
if ("DATA\\DATA" =~ m/DATA\\DATA/) {
    print "yay\n";
}
```

When you use `m//`, Perl knows that you're writing a regex and so you don't have to deal with string escapes on top of regex escapes.

Comment: Very good explanation. I recently had a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39498206/5830574) and this is a perfect addition.

Comment: At the first time, I think exactly the way you are right now. We must use "\\\\" in stead of "\\". However, it is confused that my first code still work in my computer and my second code still does not work although I use "\\\\".

Comment: if ("DATA\\\\DATA" =~ "DATA\\\\DATA") {
        print  "1\n";
}
In this case it does not print `1`.In case of my first code, It is my mistake. It get the error as you said before. PS: Sorry I dont have any idea for a line beak in here

Comment: @TuanAnhHoang You have to use the 4 backslashes only in the regex (on the right), not in the string (on the left), thus: `if ("DATA\\DATA" =~ "DATA\\\\DATA") { print "1\n"; }` prints ''1''.

Answer (score 3):

From [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> Binary "=~" binds a scalar expression to a pattern match. … The right argument is a search pattern, substitution, or transliteration. … If the right argument is an expression rather than a search pattern, substitution, or transliteration, it is interpreted as a search pattern at run time. Note that this means that its contents will be interpolated twice.

The right hand side of the `=~` is expected to be a regular expression.

If you put a string there, it will be converted to a regular expression.

So when you say:

> ```
> if ("\\" =~ "\\") {
>     print "true\n";
> }
> ```

You get:

> Trailing \ in regex m//

The literal `\\` is converted to the string `\` which is converted to regex `\` (because a `\` followed by the end is still a `\`).

This isn't a valid regex, so you get an error. I don't understand why you think *In this case it work and prints true as expected.*

In the second case the literal `DATA\\DATA` is converted to the string `DATA\DATA` which is converted to regex `DATA[^0-9]ATA`. This doesn't match `DATA\DATA` because you have two characters where it expects only one not-a-number.

---

If you are going to use `=~` then put a real regular expression on the RHS. It is much simpler.

Comment: `\D` isn't quite the same as `[^0-9]` because the former also excludes all Unicode digits.

Comment: At the first time, I think exactly the way you are right now. We must use "\\\\" in stead of "\\". However, it is confused that my first code still work in my computer and my second code still does not work although I use "\\\\".

Answer (score -2):

```
$input = "DATA\\DATA";
if ($input =~ /\\/) { print "true\n"; } else { print "false\n"; }
```

You might want to check [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: @melpomene Yeah, I'm too used to Java lately, didn't check on Perl in a long time, thanks for pointing that out (and for the irony).